# Getting the value of a cell when clicked into a Bootstrap-Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to click on a cell in a `Bootstrap-Table` table and get the value of a specific column (the `Date` column) in that row.

This code gets me the value index of the row, but my data is an array of `JSON`s. I don't think the index is helpful because I think the `array` is essentially considered unordered. Is there a way to use this index to get the value?

```
 $("#table").on("click", "tr", function (row, $el, field) {
   var row = $(this).index();
   alert(row);
    });
```

the data:

```
var data = [
    {
        "Date": "2015-02-03",
        "Contact": 1
    },
    {
        "Date": "2017-01-22",
        "Contact": 2

    }
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gv2mnwd9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pick the Date cell by the data attribute.

```
 $("#table").on("click", "tr", function (row, $el, field) {
   var date = $(this).find("a[data-name='Date']").html();
 });
```

Or

```
$("#table").on("click", "tr", function (row, $el, field) {
   var date = $(this).find("a[data-name='Date']").data('value');
 });
```

Comment: thanks, If I take away `[data-name='Date']` it also produces the correct result. What is that actually doing? Is there a way to get column name too?

Answer (score 2):

you can attached an event to td instead of tr

and get the value as follow

```
  var col = $(this)[0].textContent;
```

here is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gv2mnwd9/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something follows

```
answer = table.row(0).data().Date;
answer = table.row(0).data().Contact;
```

Update after comment >> Apologies if I have misunderstood as I thought you wanted value of a column, i hope below works for your needs.

```
                $("#table").on("click", "tr", function (row, $el, field) {

                    tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    row = table.row( tr );
                    answer = table.row(row).data().Contact;
                    alert(answer);
                });
```

Comment: Adding this to an alert does not produce any results. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, i've updated my answer - i hope ok for your needs with above.